# How can I hash an object with two symmetrically equivalent characteristics?

Tags: python, hash, geometry

I have an object (Edge) which contains two other objects (points A and B) in 3D. Geometrically, an edge from A = (0, 0, 0) to B = (1, 0, 0) should be the same as an edge from A = (1, 0, 0) to B = (0, 0, 0), and it's easy to make an equality statement of two edges. However, I'm having some conceptual problems implementing a way to hash this object (in Python). For example, hash((A, B)) will return a different value from hash((B, A)).

I've seen answers about similar problems on this site, but they all involve making a comparison between the two elements. I don't really want to do this, because while I can think of a rigorous way to compare two points (compare x-coordinates first, then y-coordinates if x are equal, then z's if y's are equal), I don't know if I want to implement a comparison which seems meaningless mathematically and only useful for this single instance. The statement (1, 0, 0) > (0, 300, 10^10) might be correct with this method, but it isn't very meaningful.

```
class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, pointA, pointB):
        self._A = pointA
        self._B = pointB
        ab = pointA + pointB
        self._midpoint = Vector(ab.x / 2, ab.y / 2, ab.z / 2)


    def get_A(self):
        return self._A

    def set_A(self, point):
        self._A = point

    def get_B(self):
        return self._B

    def set_B(self, point):
        self._B = point

    A = property(get_A, set_A)
    B = property(get_B, set_B)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Edge):
            if (self.A == other.A) and (self.B == other.B):
                return True
            elif (self.B == other.A) and (self.A == other.B):
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.A, self.B)) # =/= hash((self.B, self.A))!

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}, {}]".format(self.A, self.B)
```

In conclusion, I'm wondering if there's an implementation which will give two equivalent edges the same hash value without creating some arbitrary comparison function between points. (P.S. my "point" class is called "Vector")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the hashes of A and B with XOR:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.A) ^ hash(self.B)
```